# How can I get some value from XML int Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this sitemap in xml. How i can get each `<loc>` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Main_Page</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-10-24T03:03:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Current_Development</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-10-24T03:03:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-10-24T03:03:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

Program looks like this.

```
import os.path
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import requests
from subprocess import call

def creatingListOfBrokenLinks():
    if (os.path.isfile('sitemap.xml')):
        e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('sitemap.xml').getroot()
        file = open("all_broken_links.txt", "w")

        for atype in e.findall('url'):
            r = requests.get(atype.find('loc').text)
            print(atype)
            if (r.status_code == 404):
                file.write(atype)

        file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    creatingListOfBrokenLinks()
```

Comment: What does your python program look like at the moment?

Comment: @frankenapps i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the elementtree standard library package:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

SITEMAP = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->
    ...
    ...
</urlset>"""

urlset = ET.fromstring(SITEMAP)
loc_elements = urlset.iter("{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc")
for loc_element in loc_elements:
    print(loc_element.text)
```

Documentation links:

- [Main ElementTree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)
- [XML namespaces in ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces)

*Update:*

- What your code gets wrong is the XML namespace handling.
- Also, my example uses `.iter()` instead of `.findall()` / `.find()` to get the `loc` elements directly. This might or might not be OK depending on the structure of the XML and the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked perfectly on my end. All you had to do, is add: `{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}` before `url` and `loc`

Here:

```
import os.path
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import requests
from subprocess import call

def creatingListOfBrokenLinks():
    if (os.path.isfile('sitemap.xml')):
        e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('sitemap.xml').getroot()
        file = open("all_broken_links.txt", "w")

        for atype in e.findall('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}url'):
            r = requests.get(atype.find('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc').text)
            print(atype)
            if (r.status_code == 404):
                file.write(atype)

        file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    creatingListOfBrokenLinks()
```